# Where can I find well-written criticism about Bitcoin?

Tags: economic-theory

I couldn't find an article about criticism in the wiki. Is there some other place that contains well-constructed criticism for Bitcoin?

Comment: What kind of criticism do you mean? Some of the answers have criticism, which is not related to the economic impact if wide-spread Bitcoin adoption is achieved, which is what I suspect that you are asking, given your "economics" tag.

Comment: @David - I think the Weaknesses page is the page I'm looking for. It should incorporate all weaknesses, not just technical - edit it if you feel it's missing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here's the page on the wiki where weaknesses are addressed.](http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Weaknesses)

Comment: That's more technical weaknesses, it says nothing about the economic problems of a deflationary currency.

Comment: @r3m0t - I think the Weaknesses page is the page I'm looking for. It should incorporate all weaknesses, not just technical - edit it if you feel it's missing something.

Answer (score 0):

[This Quora question](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-primary-weaknesses-of-the-Bitcoin-protocol) is a start.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great source:
http://critiquesoflibertarianism.blogspot.co.il/2011/05/simple-critique-of-bitcoin.html

It is a short article but you can learn a lot from the comments

Answer (score 0):

See "[Decentralised Currencies Are Probably Impossible (But Let’s At Least Make Them Efficient)](http://www.links.org/?p=1179)" by Ben Laurie. He shows how Bitcoin's so-called "decentralization" is such a joke, because it doesn't really work. If Bitcoin's decentralization doesn't work, it makes no sense to waste so many resources over proof-of-work transaction processing. He also proposes an alternative design in a follow-up post.